# Can window receive input

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, window

I am working on an application and I encountered the following problem:

I need to know if another window is able to receive input and if it can, use SendKeys() to enter some text.

(for instance: I have a very slow computer and notepad takes 2 second until fully loaded - the window is created in 1 second but the controls and cursor appears only after 2 seconds so in conclusion notepad will be able to receive input only 2 seconds after launching)

I used the following code:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

private void testMethod()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad";
    p.Start();
    if (p != null)
        MessageBox.Show(IsWindowVisible(p.MainWindowHandle).ToString());
}
```

But this method will return true when the window is created, even if the components are not yet loaded.

I tried all functions at [Window functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Any reason for you not to use Automation?

Comment: Automation? please explain.
I managed to resolve my issue with WaitForInputIdle(1)